# Count of movements

Tags: mysql, select, count, sum, union

Helo, i have a table:

```
from | to   | item | count
-------
Jack | Danie| food | 10
Danie| Maria| food | 2
Jack | Peter| drink| 9
Jack | Danie| water| 1
Danie| Jack | food | 3
Jack | Alise| baks | 4
```

How i can find count of "items" in jack?

My code:

```
select sum( q1.count) as s  from (
            SELECT count, item  FROM item_movements WHERE  to = 3
            union All
            SELECT  count*-1, item  FROM item_movements WHERE from =3
            ) q1
group by item
having sum(q1.count) > 0
```

My idea: take all items from, and take all items to, union it, sum it, and take a count, but if i add select count()... its not work.

Comment: Is your aim to sum the count column for all rows containing Jack in either from and/or to?

Comment: This probably wont fix your problem but you definitely need to alias count*-1 i.e. count * -1 AS count

Comment: @JamesCulshaw You don't need an alias, the `UNION` makes the alias implicit. [Test](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9127).

Comment: just make results example.

Comment: did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

Without sub-queries:

```
SELECT SUM( IF( `from` = 'Jack', `count`, `count` * -1 ) ) `delta`
FROM `item_movements`
WHERE `from` = 'Jack' OR `to` = 'Jack'
```

(this will fail if there's any movement between 'Jack' and 'Jack')